# MATLAB complicated integration

Tags: matlab, integral

I have an integration function which does not have indefinite integral expression.

Specifically, the function is `f(y)=h(y)+integral(@(x) exp(-x-1/x),0,y) where h(y)` is a simple function.

Matlab numerically computes `f(y)` well, but I want to compute the following function.

```
g(w)=w*integral(1-f(y).^(1/w),0,inf) where w is a real number in [0,1].
```

The problem for computing `g(w)` is handling `f(y).^(1/w)` numerically.

How can I calculate `g(w)` with MATLAB? Is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Expressions containing e^(-1/x) are generally difficult to compute near x = 0. Actually, I am surprised that Matlab computes f(y) well in the first place. I'd suggest trying to compute `g(w)=w*integral(1-f(y).^(1/w),epsilon,inf)` for `epsilon` greater than zero, then gradually decreasing `epsilon` toward 0 to check if you can get numerical convergence at all. Convergence is certainly not guaranteed!

Comment: Since the limit of exp(-1/x) as x approaches 0 from the right exists for real x, the integral is convergent from 0 to any real x.  The complication arises when integrating over the complex numbers from 0.

Comment: @TroyHaskin, good point. Convergence of the integral is certainly guaranteed, but I have doubts about *numerical* convergence of `g(w)`. It seems to me that `x` and `w` could play off one another in a bad way when they both approach zero.

Comment: Kielpinkski Oh yeah, I definitely agree that `w` going to 0 may be a big problem as well.  I was focusing on f(y) only.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate `g(w)` using the functions you have, but you need to add the (`ArrayValued`,`true`) name-value pair.
The option allows you to specify a vector-valued `w` *and* allows the nested `integral` call to receive a vector of `y` values, which is how `integral` naturally works.

```
f = @(y) h(y)+integral(@(x) exp(-x-1/x),0,y,'ArrayValued',true);
g = @(w) w .* integral(1-f(y).^(1./w),0,Inf,'ArrayValued',true);
```

At least, that works on my R2014b installation.

---

Note: While `h(y)` may be simple, if it's integral over the positive real line does not converge, `g(w)` will more than likely not converge (I don't think I need to qualify that, but I'll hedge my bets).